Are the Statlines of the Kusarigama and Manriki-Gusari flipped?
Mage 20th anniversary edition offers some weapons. In fact, it offers the most extensive weapon toybox in all 20th anniversary edition books. Among them is the category of "whips and chains".1



Weapon
Difficulty
Damage/Type
Conceal
Notes




Kusarigama
7
Strength +3 /B
T
#2, #6


Manriki-Gusari
7
Strength +2 /L
T
#2, #6



Now... you see, a Manriki-Gusari is also known as a "Weighted Chain", while a Kusarigama is a sickle (Kama) with a chain and weight on the end. But the sickle has the bashing damage, while the weighted chain has the lethal one...
Is there an errata or official acknowledgment that those two stat lines have errors?

1 - Mage 20th Anniversary Edition, p.451.
